# Jmeter- no results obtained using jmeter distributed system

Tags: jmeter

Im running Jmeter test with one master machine and slave system. The issue is Im not getting the results from the slave system, even though I could see the test has started and finished in slave system.

[image]
[image]

I tried running another Jmeter test with a different script & same configuration and fortunately Im able to get the results from the slave system.
Im not able to understand why the first scenario is not working and where exactly is the issue. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshots I can only state that the test didn't produce a single SampleResult because it didn't execute any [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers), the most common reasons are:

1. Your test is using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and you forgot to copy the CSV file on slave machines. JMeter master only transfers the [.jmx test plan](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) to slaves, everything else needs to be copied manually
2. Basically a subset of point 1: your test plan relies on a [JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) which is not present on the slaves. If this is the case - install the missing plugin(s) using the [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

The exact failure reason can be found in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) on master machine and jmeter-server.log files on slave machines.

Comment: > Your test is using CSV Data Set Config and you forgot to copy the CSV file on slave machines. 

You could use the Http Simple Table Server to manage your csv files easily with all slaves
[https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/)